# Connecting to Oracle with encrypted pwd

Tags: oracle, encryption

I am reading my userid , pwd from a file with 400 permissions to connect to the external oracle application.

Now my requirement is that i should not use the plain text pwd present in the file . I should use some encrypted pwd to connect. How i can do this ?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you would want to use an [Oracle wallet](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/cnctslsh.htm) so that you don't need to embed the username and password in your application at all.  Depending on the architecture of your application, there may be other options as well-- if you're building a Java application that is deployed to an application server, for example, most application servers have a way to configure connection pools such that only the encrypted password is stored in a configuration file.